# Python 3 changing variable inside function without using global variables

Tags: python

So i am currently working on a university project, therefore i can't really paste my code to be more specific, but we have this stupid rule that global variables are not allowed and using them would lead to points removal. So my question is:
I am making a  roll the dice game, where a couple of players take turns and i need a variable that identifies which player is on turn. I have a function, which represents each turn and a second, which calls the first function multiple times, which is equal to the number of players. Lets say i have 3 players:

```
def func1():
    player_on_turn = 1
    result = 0
    print('Player',player_on_turn,'is on turn.')
    #something
    return result

def func2():
    players = 3 
    for player in range(1,players+1):
        player = func1()

func2()
```

So this variable player_on_turn has to change 3 times, meaning for each call of the function. The first call it is equal to 1, the second to 2, etc.
I've done this already with global variable, but apparently i can't use them, because "it makes the code hard to read". In the first function i am already using return for a one value which changes inside the function and is being reset each call. Is there a way i could probably do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how function parameters work? You passed in arguments to the `range()` function, you can do the same with your own functions. `func1()` can take a parameter, `player_on_turn`. See the [Python tutorial on functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: How about passing `player` as an input to `func1` in `func2`?

Comment: It's not a stupid rule, it's a very sensible rule. Modifiable globals break modularity, and make code harder to read and to debug.

Comment: The thing is that the first function has already a few parameters, which i can't change or add new ones.(by default)

Comment: If the first function already has a few parameters then the code in your question needs to show that. And if you aren't permitted to change the function's parameters you should say so in the question itself. It would make it easier for people to help you if you post a [mcve] that focuses on your problem. If you really cannot pass the number of the current player to `func1` that's annoying, and there are ways around that which don't involve modifiable globals, but it would be _far_ better to simply pass it into the function.

Comment: Yup, its my bad that i haven't mentioned it in the beginning. So yeah, basically i can't pass it as a parameter to the function, because it has already a couple and i am not allowed to add new ones, which kinda makes the problem harder to deal with. So any suggestions are welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Function Parameters](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html#FunctionParameters) to pass data between functions.

You can also use a [Class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to create objects that store data without global variables.